# Explain Highcharts different Instantiations

Tags: highcharts

I have a perfectly good Highcharts example that is initiated with the code commencing:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
```

When I replace this with the following code it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
       renderTo: '#container1,
            type: 'line'
        },
```

Can someone explain the difference, and why it does not work? as I said, all the other code is absolutley identical and works fine for the first example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the closing quote in the `renderTo` option.

```
renderTo: '#container1',
```

Also, your container ID's are different (`container` vs `container1`). Not sure if that was intentional.

Comment: Great! Glad to help :) Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way. Since this answer helped you out, would you mind accepting it? Thanks!